# Изменение изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Подскажите, как написать простенький скрипт на `php` для изменения изображения при загрузке на сайт через форму.

Comment: Для изменения чего?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/image.examples.php

Comment: нужно изменять изображение (равномерно) до нужных размеров. Вообще интересно как реализована такая функция при загрузке аватарки Вконтакте, может кто объяснит

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще [Imagic](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).
Очень много чего умеет.

Comment: может как то можно на javascript или jquery выделить фрагмент при загрузке изображения , потом на php сохранить его вписав в нужный блок на странице а при нажатии оно должно увеличиваться, что то вроде загрузки авы Вконтакте.